# My mongodb service is crashed with the following error, and I am unable to find the root cause from the mongodb logs

Tags: database, mongodb

Mongodb service crashed and this was the error I noticed in logs

**2020-12-20T06:25:03.184+0000 I COMMAND  [conn303] getmore local.oplog.rs query: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 16084451500|5 } } cursorid: ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 exception: interrupted at shutdown code:1 numYields:0 nreturned:1 reslen:69 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { R: 4 } } } 2052ms**

I would like to know what causes mongodb service to crash like this? afterwards, mongodb service stopped and shutted down, Any reason for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a crash report. The server is saying that it was asked to shut down and it aborted a query that was being executed. This is normal behavior.

Comment: just after this message, mongodb service stopped suddenly and stopped acception connections, why is that?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. Retrieve the relevant information from the server log and create a new question with that.